# Laravel 7 - Redirecting different user roles to different view

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, roles, user-roles

- The LoginController had this code before:

```
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function showLoginForm(){
            $roles = Role::all();
            return view('auth.login', compact('roles'));
        }
    
        public function logout(Request $request){
            Auth::logout();
            $request->session()->flush();
            return redirect('/');
        }
    
        public function login()
        {
            $credentials = $this->validate(request(),[
                'email' => 'email|required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ]);
    
           
            if (Auth::attempt ($credentials)){//auth attemptdevuelve verdadero o falso en caso de que las credenciales correspondan o no
            //Inician cambios RDAN
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->userRole() == 'admin') {
                return redirect('main');
            } else if($user->userRole() == 'externo') {
                return redirect('es/user_form');
            } else if($user->userRole() == 'profesor') {
                return redirect('profesor_site');
            } else if($user->userRole() == 'registrador') {
                return redirect('select_lang');
            } else {
                return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Incorrect user permissions']) 
                ->withInput(request(['email']));
            }
            //Terminan cambios RDAN
                    
            }else{
            return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Incorrect user permissions']) 
            ->withInput(request(['email'])); }
        }
    }
```

- Then I changed it for:

```
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
      use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/main';//RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
    }
```

- In the model User I have this for the roles:

```
     public function roles()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'assigned_roles');
        }
    
        public function isAdmin(){
            return $this->hasRoles(['admin']);
        }
    
        public function hasRoles(array $roles)
        {
            return $this->roles->contains(fn($role, $key) => in_array($role->name, $roles));
        }
    
        public function userRole(){
            return $this->role->nombre_rol;
        }
```

With the new changes on the LoginController I have no problem with the login, but obviously only redirect to the main view. So, I want to add the redirect view depend on the role, but when I add the `public function login()` that it had before it returns an error with the `function userRole()` on the model User. The error is

> ErrorException
> Trying to get property 'nombre_rol' of non-object
> http://localhost/Servescol2.0.2/public/login

Comment: what is `$this->role` on the model supposed to be? also you dont need to override the `login` method on the `LoginController`, you can override the `authenticated` method which you can return a response from and it is called after the user is authenticated

Comment: `$this->role` It's supposed to obtain the name of the role and in the LoginController if the user role is 'admin' it redirects to the correspondent view.

Comment: obtain the name of what role? the User belongs to many Roles

Comment: Ok, I get it now. So, `$this->role` it's not needed and I need to change this conditions  `if($user->userRole() == 'admin') {}`  on the `login`?

Comment: use the methods already in place. for admin `if ($user->isAdmin())` for other roles `if ($user->hasRoles(['externo'])`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to override the `login` method. The `login` method currently will make a call to the `authenticated` method to see if it returns true truthy value and then return that as the response. You can override the `authenticated` method and have it return your redirect based on your conditions.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->hasRoles(['admin'])) {
        return redirect('main');
    }
    ...
}
```

The error is caused by trying to access an attribute/relationship which doesn't exist, which returns `null`:

```
$this->role
```

The User belongs to many Role so there are multiple roles not a single one.

You could have a method to check for a single role:

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
}
```

Then you could adjust your conditionals:

```
if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
```

Or use the `hasRoles` method instead:

```
if ($user->hasRoles(['admin']) {
```